# afterRender threw an error in 'c:componentName' [Maximum call stack size exceeded] in LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I was playing with getter and setter in Lightning Web Component and ended up with below code:-

```
@api
    get itemName() {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('@@ this.uppercaseItemName from getter @@'+this.uppercaseItemName);
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('@@ itemName from getter @@'+this.itemName);
        return this.uppercaseItemName;
    }

    set itemName(value) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('@@ itemName from setter @@'+this.itemName);
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('@@ this.uppercaseItemName from setter @@'+value.toUpperCase());
       this.uppercaseItemName = value.toUpperCase();
    }
```

I am calling the getter inside the getter and know it is causing the issue. It results in:-

[image]

It says:-

> afterRender threw an error in 'c:componentName' [Maximum call stack
>   size exceeded]

In debug log, i have:-

[image]

This console.log('@@ this.uppercaseItemName from getter @@'+this.uppercaseItemName); has been executed **999** times and it results into error - **Maximum call stack size exceeded**.

The question is what is the criteria in LWC framework to result in above error? Is it **999** times execution of the code recursively? What other scenario can result into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question is what is the criteria in LWC framework to result in above error?

Any computer program execution environment has a maximum stack size, including JavaScript. This error is coming directly from the browser's JavaScript engine, not LWC.

> Is it 999 times execution of the code recursively?

Yes, that's it.

> What other scenario can result into it?

Any time you write a recursive function, you run into the risk of such an error.

For example:

```
fib(n) {
  return n < 2? n: fib(n-1)+fib(n-2);
}
```

This is a recursive function that calculates the n-th Fibonacci number, which is defined as a series of numbers where the next number is derived from adding the two precious numbers together:

```
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 ...
```

If you try to calculate the 1000th or so Fibonacci number, you'd get this same error.

In practice, this is pretty rare, but it can happen. Always keep recursion in mind. This error is designed to keep your browser from crashing entirely due to using too much stack.

If you don't know what the stack is, I'd suggest reading about it on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) or elsewhere. It's a very important concept to understand in computing, as virtually every computer in the world, every programming language you'll ever use, **everything** needs stacks, and they are always finite in size.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @sfdcfox

Answer (score -1):

Set the item as uppercase only if it is not already uppercase, else you generate an infinite loop :)

```
@api

get itemName() {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('@@ this.uppercaseItemName from getter @@'+this.uppercaseItemName);
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('@@ itemName from getter @@'+this.itemName);
        return this.uppercaseItemName;
}

set itemName(value) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('@@ itemName from setter @@'+this.itemName);
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('@@ this.uppercaseItemName from setter @@'+value.toUpperCase());
    if ( this.uppercaseItemName !== value.toUpperCase() ) {
        this.uppercaseItemName = value.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not my question is about. The question is what is the criteria in LWC framework to result in Maximum call stack size exceeded error? Is it 999 times execution of the code recursively? What other scenario can result into it?

Comment: I know that calling the getter inside the getter is resulting the issue but not sure about the limits in Lightning Web Component.

Comment: This is a recursive stack call, it's more javascript oriented than LWC oriented. I don't really see the point of making wrong code on purpose and asking why it is wrong code :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826992/browser-javascript-stack-size-limit . And SFDC probably set it at 999. But again, what is the point ? :)

Comment: It is to understand the lwc framework. This error is no where documented in lwc developer guide and i don't know about it.